# Side effect network request

Tags: ios, combine

I fetch a data from RestAPI and after receiving a value I have to send another network request which has an important delay and has no impact on first fetch. I would like to use `handleEvents` publisher operator but this one is in Apple documentation in Debugging section. If I use `flatMap` then my sink will wait a result of second fetch but it has no impact on my main stream. Is there any other way to start a network call which has no impact on main stream/pipeline ?

Example 1: This one looks fine but `handleEvents` is in Debugging section of Apple documentation

[image]

```
    cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: .init(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/1")!)
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in
             cancellable2 = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: .init(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/10")!)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    print(completion)
                }, receiveValue: { value in
                    print(value)
                })
        }
        .sink { completion in
            print(completion)
        } receiveValue: { value in
            print(value)
        }
```

---

Example 2: this one makes my main stream to wait of result of second resumed from `flatMap` which makes my stream to wait for finished signal

```
    cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: .init(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/1")!)
        .flatMap { _ in
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: .init(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/10")!)
        }
        .sink { completion in
            print(completion)
        } receiveValue: { value in
            print(value)
        }
```

Comment: I like to show you another problem with your code. -> If your first call is failed, you cannot make that network request manually again. ( but can do with retry - not manually when the user needs it)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways. with this, you can send the first request multiple times even if the first call throws an error.

```swift
let startFirst = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
  let startSecond = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
  
  let cancellable =
  startFirst
      .flatMap { _ in
          URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: .init(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/1")!)
          // handle errors
      }
      .sink { completion in
          print(completion)
      } receiveValue: { value in
          print(value)
          startSecond.send(())
      }
  
  let cancellable2 =
  startSecond
      .flatMap({ _ in
          URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: .init(string: "http://httpbin.org/delay/10")!)
          // handle errors
      })
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
          print(completion)
      }, receiveValue: { value in
          print(value)
      })
  
  startFirst.send(()) // start first network request
```